# MYSQL - Cannot able to create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am using MYSQL 5.1. When i am going create a table, it throws error like this,

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_status (
  STATUS_ID int(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  STATUS_NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  DESC varchar(100) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (STATUS_ID),
  UNIQUE KEY XPKPAYMENT_STATUS (STATUS_ID)
)
```

Error:

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC varchar(100) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (STATUS_ID),
  UNIQUE KEY XPKPAYMENT_STATUS (S' at line 4
(0 ms taken)
```

Comment: Why are you adding  UNIQUE KEY XPKPAYMENT_STATUS if you already have declared it as a primary key

Comment: Where is the check box to accept. I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESC` is a reserved word, wrap it around with backticks..

```
`DESC`
```

Comment: Yes this is the error, After i renamed this word as description, it works fine.
Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

`DESC` is a reserved MYSQL word (ever used `ORDER BY Column1 DESC`???).

Enclose the word in backticks (`) and query will run fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_status (
  STATUS_ID int(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  STATUS_NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `DESC` varchar(100) ,
  /* note the backticks on the above line */
  PRIMARY KEY (STATUS_ID),
  UNIQUE KEY XPKPAYMENT_STATUS (STATUS_ID)
)
```

Though I recommend renaming the column to avoid further trouble.